# Can't send mail with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtp, email, smtpclient, email-client

Can't send mail. Here is my `C#` source:

```
  var to = "me@mycompany.com";
  var subject = "test";
  var body = "test mail";
  var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
  var client = new SmtpClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@mycompany.com", "mypassword") };
  client.Send(message);
```

here is the `App.config`:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="me@mycompany.com">
        <network
          host="mail.mycompany.com"
          port="25"
          userName="me@mycompany.com"
          password="mypassword"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

So far, if the host/port in `App.config` are wrong an exception is thrown, but not if user/pass are wrong (obvious security reasons). However, I've succeeded to log-in from Microsof Outlook with just the same user/pass as in the source.

The email is not received, nor in `Inbox`, neither in `Junk` folder. How can I validate the server-side (considering it's a part of microsoftonline.com)? What am I missing? What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Which exceptiona are you getting? Please include it as part of this query

Comment: What happens if you connect using `telnet mail.mycompany.com 25`? If your organisation is running on Microsoft Exchange then logging onto SMTP might not be as straightforward as connecting to port 25 and supplying a user name and password. For instance, the server might demand that you connect using SSL.

Comment: @Jangwenyi: the exceptions tell that host/port are wrong, which is a good thing. However, when exceptions are not thrown, the email is still not received.

Comment: @Tim: I've tried that a while ago, got connected (but not authenticated, of course). We have a continuous integration server that connects to mail.mycompany.com with identical parameters and mails are issued on the regular basis.

Comment: @BreakPhreak, another corporate SMTP gotcha that comes to mind is IP address white listing. Your CI server might be on the approved list, but your test machine not.

Comment: @Tim: I am sending from the same laptop the Microsoft Outlook smoothly works from.

Comment: OK, but are you sure Outlook connects directly through SMTP? In my experience, when connected to Exchange, it uses the proprietary Exchange RPC protocol.

Comment: I'll try to find some "pure" SMTP server to check with. Maybe you are right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got an answer from the IT team - it was a configuration/security issue. Solved with IT. Thanks a lot, everyone.

Comment: ok, but how? that would be nice to explain. it was not an accepted answer for anyone but you

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that if server rejects the email for any reason your code would throw an exception.  If it is not then that implies that the server is accepting the emails with the supplied user name and password and technically the mails are "sending" successfully.  However this is no guarantee that anyone will receive any emails.  You need to find out what the email server is doing with these emails and why.

Comment: I've asked our IT team to open a ticket with microsoftonline support. However, as a developer I still want to do any homework I can meanwhile.

Comment: I understand but unfortunately i don't think there is much you can do, if the serrver is accepting the emails but not delivering them then technically your code is working, if you are doing something wrong you will not find out anything useful until you hear back from support.  If you are paying for a hosted service be prepared for them to say that sending emails programatically is not supported.

Comment: The CI (Continuous Integration server) succeeds to send mails fluently. And this way or another - I am looking for any kind of server-side validation I can (should try to) perform. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "server side validation", which server are you refering to?

Comment: I mean the exchange server I am trying to send the mails via it. But as I've wrote above, while talking to you guys I've got that maybe the best situation would be to install some SMTP server locally, check with it and forget.

Comment: Yes that would be the best solution.  You would not be able to validate anything with an SMTP server, there is no "what happened to my email" option in the SMTP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The link below has an example of a very simple send email function that can be called from a console application to test. I know this code works, so it could isolate any issue with your code and maybe shed a little more light on where the issue is.

[SendEmail() – Create and Send Email Messages in C#](http://www.bytechaser.com/en/functions/sdnz2ydstm/sendemail-create-and-send-email.aspx)

Comment: yeah, just as my code, actually :) meanwhile got an official IT response - it was a network/security configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having firewall issues trying to use smtp as well. This is a work-around if you don't want to work with IT and do have outlook installed. This method will use your default email to send though.  You will also need to add a reference (I'm using under COM 'Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library')

```
     using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

     private void sendEmail(string DistributionList, string AttachmentDestination)
      {
        //new outlook instance
        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();

        //new mail object
        Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        mail.Subject = "This is coming from a C# script";
        mail.To = DistributionList; //your distribution list "email@something.com"
        mail.Body = "This is the body of an email from a C# script";
        mail.Attachments.Add(AttachmentDestination); //location of attachment (can be ommitted)
        mail.Send();
        app.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: this has proven to be extremely unreliable